# How can i receive messages through an MDB remotely in Wildfly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, hornetq, message-driven-bean

I've got two Wildfly servers running on different machines, one of which will be sending JMS messages to the other. I've created a simple test application that seems to be sending messages but the other side is not receiving. In fact it's already complaining that it can't connect:

```
14:17:21,188 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (MSC service thread 1-6) HQ122018: Could not start recovery discovery on XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=ca25380b-c270-11e4-ac81-876cdf81429b, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5545&host=192-168-179-25&local-address=127-0-0-1], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=****], we will retry every recovery scan until the server is available
14:17:21,296 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 1) HQ151005: awaiting HornetQ Server availability
14:17:23,300 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 1) HQ151001: Attempting to reconnect org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@6d148215 destination=jms/queue/myqueue destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15)
```

I've tried many things when configuring both servers. Part of the configuration of the producing server:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
        <hornetq-server>
            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
            </acceptors>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="myQueue">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/myqueue"/>
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/myqueue"/>
                </jms-queue>

            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

and of the consuming server:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
        <hornetq-server>
            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging-remote"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
            </acceptors>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="myQueue">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/myqueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="messaging-remote">
        <remote-destination host="192.168.179.25" port="5545"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Hope someone can give me a hint on this. I have a feeling this should be very easy.

Comment: Are they running on different "boxes" (or VMs)?

Comment: Yes I'll clarify my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working. Some important points:

- The messaging-remote port in the consuming server configuration should of course point to the same port as in the producing server (5445).
- A user needs to be created using the bin/add-user.sh tool. The MDB then needs two ActivationConfigProperty's:

  ```
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "jms"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "password")
  ```
- Very importantly, the standalone-full.xml config by default only allows local traffic, so you have to reconfigure the public interface in the producing server:

  ```
  <interface name="public">
      <any-address/>
  </interface>
  ```

or maybe something slightly less permissive.

Comment: Same problem I am facing in wildfly 24 , I tired this soltion I was getting error.